# (jQuery + Mobile) Target data in a div to write to variable

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Is it possible to find particular data inside an element on a click, and then write that data to a variable)?

For example, I have a list, with elements of class "datasource" that navigate to "#dataviewer":

```
<ul>
   <li class="datasource">
      <a href="#dataviewer" >Get this data</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

I know I can target that specific list element using something like this:

```
$(".datasource").click(function() {
        alert("Click!");
});
```

... but can I fetch the "Get this data" and write it to a variable, in order to use that data on the '#datasource' page?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Get this data" is able to be retrieved by the `.html()` function. Switch out your alert for the following:

```
alert($("a").html());
```

You can obviously be as selective as you want to find the "a" element based on the rest of your page.

To store the value into a variable, just store that output like this:

```
// Probably not exactly what you want when there are many "a"nchor tags on a page.
var contentsOfElement = $("a").html();
// More selective based on an ID
var contentsOfElement = $("#oneParticularID").html();
// Then you can write that text, store it, or whatever you'd like
```

Using your code as a template, I created this [running example](http://jsfiddle.net/zSg3K/).

[The documentation](http://api.jquery.com/html/) for `.html()`.

Comment: Hmm... it seems not to like something, because it just alerts "Submit" when I do alert($("a").html()); and when I pass it to a variable and alert the variable it says the same

Comment: @Squishy; you need to be more specific with your selector. $("a") will capture every anchor on the page. It was just an example for when you only have one "a" on the page. See my edited answer for how to find an element by an id. Be sure to give your anchor an id such as `<a id='whateverYouDecide'>`

Comment: @Squishy; you're welcome! Be sure to go to the jQuery documentation as often as you have questions; it is very good at showing you what the language is capable of. Glad you got your question answered

Answer (score 1):

With a listview like this:

```
<div data-role="page">
<ul data-role="listview">
   <li class="datasource">
      <a href="#dataviewer" >Row A</a>
   </li>
   <li class="datasource">
      <a href="#dataviewer" >Row B</a>
   </li>

</ul>
</div>​​​​​​​
```

You could use a click handler like this:

```
​$(".datasource").click (function () {
   alert( $(this).find('a').first().html() );
});​​​​​
```

Comment: Does .first() only fetch the data on the first click, but nothing subsequent?

Comment: `find('a')` returns an array. `first()` gets the first entry in the array.